# Django models.CASCADE in ManyToManyRelation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a m2m relationship with users and posts. A user can like a many posts and at the same time  a post can be liked by many users.

If i do this:

```
post.liked_by.remove(current_user)
```

With this model structure:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)

class User(AbstractUser):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followed_by')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Posts, related_name='liked_by')
    pass
```

As far as i know, the user object will be removed from the `liked_by` part of the relationship.

But my question is:
Will also the post object be removed from the `likes` part of the relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the relationship will be removed.

`remove(*objs, bulk=True)`

Removes the specified model objects from the related object set.

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove)

There are also more [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)